# Complex power series property with real numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

I am trying to prove the following statement, seems clear to me but I am not able to give a formal proof. I have tried using the binomial expansion and Taylor's theorem for complex numbers.

Let $f(z)= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$  be a power series with radius of convergence $R_1=\infty$.

Prove that $f(z-c), c \in \mathbb{R}$ can also be written as a power series $f(z-c)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$ with radius of convergence $R_2=\infty$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

- Function $f(z)$ defined by the power series is [analytic within the radius of converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Analytic_functions)
- Function $h(z)=z-c$ is analytic (entire in fact)
- $g(z)=(f\circ h)(z)$ is [also analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Properties_of_analytic_functions)

You can tighten the result by the fact that $f(z)$ is in fact [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) and deduct that $g(z)$ is also entire.